# Celery beat doesn't pick up tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a task that is supposed to run every minute and a celery worker. I have placed the `celery.py` into my main project folder, where `wsgi.py` is located and it looks like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'TestTask.settings')

app = Celery('TestTask')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(60.0, print_hw(), name="print_hw")


@app.task
def print_hw():
    print('hello_world')

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'print_hello_world': {
        'task': 'tasks.print_hw',
        'schedule': 10.0,
    }
}

app.conf.timezone = "UTC"
```

But when I run the command `celery -A TestTask beat` I only see the following in the console:

```
celery beat v5.3.1 (emerald-rush) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2023-08-30 14:20:04
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%WARNING
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
```

And nothing happens afterwards, i.e. tasks aren't being identified/executed by the worker. Any idea what I did wrong here or what can be the problem?

Comment: It turns out I had some currupted tasks in my db, using django admin and deleting them from `Crontabs` resolved my Issue, also I had to run the beater and the worker at the same time.